# Can anybody explain these numbers for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand the things in bold:

> Of the 40 occasions since 1928 in which an industry rose by at least 100% over any two-year period, a collapse of more than **40%** over the subsequent two years occurred **53%** of the time — or 21 times, as noted above.

Source: http://www.barrons.com/articles/are-we-in-a-stock-market-bubble-1490261265?google_editors_picks=true

There are lots of things that are confusing. Does "40% over the next two years" mean the same as "40% of the next two years"?

Does 53% of the time mean "50% of the two years"?

If so, how does the meaning of the whole sentence fit together?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about how to understand percentages.

Comment: @TRo I don't think this is any different from other comprehension questions. It's not about what "53 %" means but what it's referring to.

Comment: Your question is about how to understand numbers, @haile. That's what's wrong with it. It's not about the English language. It is about as off-topic as a question can get here.

Comment: I totally disagree with you, TRomano.

Comment: Your question does not say what it is about the *language* that makes it difficult for you to understand the passage. That you cannot get your head around the numbers is not relevant here.

Comment: @haile Please [be nice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and try to focus on the question itself when commenting, not on other users.  Comments of that nature about other users are not acceptable here, but you can certainly explain why you feel your question is on-topic, as M.A.R. does in his comment.

Comment: I agree with @TRomano.  I can see how this sentence might be confusing, but OP hasn't given any information what, exactly, is most problematic -- for example, haile could offer a "best guess".  Instead it's just asking us to explain it.

Comment: @TRomano Yes, but just put the percentages into words instead of figures and its clearly a comprehension issue.

Comment: @TRomano It is the semantic relations between the numbers (which could just as easily be words as figures) and verbs and phrases in the sentence that causes the difficulty - which is why this is a standard type of problem that you have to tackle in IELTS and TOEFL English exams.

Comment: @Araucaria: Our goal is to help learners understand language, not numbers. The question makes no attempt to describe the nature of the *linguistic* issue that is confusing the OP or is otherwise opaque. It simply bolds numeric representations which are universally understood by any numerate nine year old.   "I don't quite understand the things in bold". And that the OP understands what those numeric representations mean (i.e. it's not a typography question) is clear from the fact that theOP has accepted an answer which does not explain these glyphs typographically.

Comment: @TRomano There's no explanation of *numbers* of any sort in the answer  - which shows that the problem has nothing to do with numbers.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for adding more detail. If that detail had been included originally in the question, we could have avoided a lot of trouble :)

Comment: @ColleenV I agree, but I do think it can be very difficult to put your finger on what's making it difficult for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's implying that whenever the industry rose, an unexpected collapse happening in two years is common.

Industry rises by 100 %, then

- Within a two-year time span from the rise, in 21 occasions out of 40, or **53 %** of the time, there is a **40 %** collapse.
- In 19 occasions out of 40, or 47 percent of the time, there isn't a **40 %** collapse.